# Events when loading several Vector Tiles

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I am using several vector tiles in my map (more than 10). I intend to show a loading gif for each layer so I followed [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/tile-load-events.html) as a starting point.

The thing is that, before a layer is completely loaded, the number of loaded tiles are equal to the number of loading tiles which should only occur when all tiles are loaded. Not before.

This is a sample of what is happening.

1. One tile of layer A starts loading.
2. One tile of layer B starts loading.
3. One tile of layer A gets loaded ---> ATTENTION !!!! Loading == loaded for layer A before all tiles of layer A are loaded!!
4. One tile of layer C starts loading.
5. One tile of layer A starts loading.

Any ideas on how I should approach this?